# Windows 10 not respecting iWindowPosDX and iWindowPosDY settings

Tags: windows-10

I have a batch file opening several notepad documents in specific locations. I am changing the windows registry before every document so it will open in the location desired and with the sized desired. While all windows open in the desired location not all of them open with the desired size.
example:

```
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDX /t REG_DWORD /d 1402 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDY /t REG_DWORD /d 682 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosX /t REG_DWORD /d 4294965889 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosY /t REG_DWORD /d 585 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v fWrap /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

start "" "file1.txt"

rem *****

reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDX /t REG_DWORD /d 674 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDY /t REG_DWORD /d 837 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosX /t REG_DWORD /d 4294966192 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosY /t REG_DWORD /d 219 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v fWrap /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

start "" "file2.txt"

rem *****

reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDX /t REG_DWORD /d 540 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosDY /t REG_DWORD /d 837 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosX /t REG_DWORD /d 4294965665 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v iWindowPosY /t REG_DWORD /d 219 /f
reg ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" /v fWrap /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f


start "" "file3.txt"
```

Most of the time file #1 will have a different size, sometimes it will have the correct size. File 2 for the most always has the right size and file 3 I dont recall a time the size was wrong.

However, if I cut and paste to a cmd window any of those commands they files always open in the right place and right size....

I have attempt to slow down the speed at which the block of commands but still the same outcome.

Comment: Here are two programs that can size or move a window. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/sizewindowexe-changes-size-of-window.html and https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/movewindowexe-moves-window.html

Comment: My scripts to change notepad position before opening notepad worked fine with Windows 10 but no longer work with Windows 11. I'm looking for a fix. For mine I call vbscript and pass arguments for greater control and the bat file does not proceed until the vbscript finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Need to reboot pc after editing registry for changes to take effect.

Comment: Incorrect. You must only make sure the program that reads the registry is unloaded before changing the registry, then load. Rebooting is required when changing entries the OS reads.